# How do I estimate a state space model, if I know all the states and have an approximation model?

Tags: matrices, control-theory, parameter-estimation, optimal-control, kalman-filter

Let's say that a got an approximation state space mode:

$$\dot{x}(t) = Ax(t) + Bu(t)$$
$$y(t) = Cx(t) + Du(t)$$

All a know is that this state space model is just an approximation for the real process. But I have measured all the states over time $x(t)$

So I can add a vector to this state space mode:

$$\dot{x}(t) = A\theta x(t) + B\theta u(t)$$
$$y(t) = C\theta x(t) + D\theta u(t)$$

Where
$$ \theta = \begin{bmatrix} a_1\\ a_2\\ \vdots \\ a_n\\ \end{bmatrix} $$

Then I need to choose the parameters $a_1, a_2, ... , a_n$ to make sure that the model is correct.

How do I choose the parameters $a_1, a_2, ... , a_n$ ?

Notice that $\theta$ is not a vector who going to change matrix $A$, only add some scalar to the system.

I might have wrong about this method, but my cource in system identification only teach out the theory.

Edit:
Is there a better way to estimate a state space model?

Comment: This does not seem correct: $A$ should be an $n\times n$ matrix such that $Ax(t)$ remains $n\times 1$ like $x(t)$. But now you have $A\theta x(t)$, and $A\theta$ becomes  a scalar.  
The easiest thing to do is to do a least squares fit, using $x_{[k+1]} = x_k + A x_k \Delta T$ (I'm going to discrete time since you have measurements, which I assume to be discrete), treating the elements of A as unknowns. You can do a lot of variations that assume more or less of the structure is already correct. NOTE this is for the uncontrolled case where you only care about A, I leave the rest to you.

Comment: Ok! But when it comes to least squares, do I need to know the form on the A-matrix then? Or do I only need the measurements?

Comment: The size of the $A$ matrix you can fit depends of course on your measurements. I'm assuming you have measurements that you know correspond to all your states, and you can therefore just fit the actual $A$. Is that (dimension) what you mean by structure? If yes, then you only need your measurements. If you mean more like the internal structure, you can perhaps use that to improve your fit.

Comment: Yes. I mean dimension. But isin't an extended kalman filter a took to estimate a state space model ?

Comment: Not exactly, but in any case yes you can make things more complicated to deal with things like noise, sensing that does not directly correspond to state, etc.
I'm assuming you want to deal with the simplest vanilla problem... if that's not the case, please give a more complete description of your system.

Comment: Well, it's an hydraulic system. And all I want to do is to get a state space model from that hydraulic system. The system contains cylinders, stiffness, damping, intertia, motors etc. Classical mechanics.